# Redirect Wordpress Permalink in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I want to change the permalink structure of my site from /%postname%/ to /%category%/%post_id%/%postname%/ , and have the old backlinks redirect to the new structure (currently getting 404's). I have tried a couple of different redirection plugins (Redirection, 301 Simple Plugins) and I can't get them to work.

Can someone show me the rule to put in the htaccess file instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the explicit category and post_id for a given postname, then you can create the redirects individually:

```
Redirect 301 /example-post-name-to-redirect/ /example-category/1234/example-post-name-to-redirect/
```

or using mod_rewrite (note, these rules *must be before* your wordpress rules:

```
RewriteRule ^example-post-name-to-redirect/$ /example-category/1234/example-post-name-to-redirect/ [L,R=301]
```

But the better solution is just using wordpress to do this for you, have you tried: [UrbanGiraffe Redirection plugin](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/), [Scott Yang's Permalink Redirect WordPress Plugin](http://scott.yang.id.au/code/permalink-redirect/), or [Yoast's Permalink Redirect WordPress Plugin](http://yoast.com/wordpress/permalink-redirect/)?

Comment: Hi, my site has 1000's of posts so doing this manually for every post would definitely not be ideal. 

I have tried the UrbanGiraffe one (no luck), but I'll give the other two a try as well.

Comment: Hi again, the plugin from Yoast worked a charm (the other did not). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the Redirection Wordpress Plugin you must add your old structure to Site->Permalink Migrations, something like this:
/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/

On the .htaccess file you must use regex like this one:
RedirectMatch 301 /^/\d{4}/\d{2}/(.*) https://yourdomain.com/$1/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).